# Issue creating multiple threads with pthreads

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, ubuntu, pthreads

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>


void *compute() {

float total;
int i;
float oldtotal =0, result =0;

for(i=0;i<1999999999;i++)
{
    result =sqrt(1001.0)*sqrt(1001.0);  
}

printf ("Result is %f\n", result);
oldtotal = total;
total = oldtotal + result;

printf("Total is %f\n",total);

return NULL;


}


int main() {


pthread_t thread1, thread2;

pthread_create(&thread1, NULL,compute, NULL); 

pthread_create(&thread2, NULL,compute, NULL); 


pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
pthread_join(thread2, NULL);

return 0;
}
```

Only one thread is created when I run the program. I've checked this using the top command in cmd, the process runs at 197% so I believe two processes are being run. I've remembered to compile it with the -pthreads flag.

Comment: How do you know that "only one thread is created"?

Comment: If the process is running at over 100% then you definitely have multiple threads. The `top` command, by default, doesn't show threads only processes.

Comment: How do I split this up to show multiple processes?

Comment: I dispute this question, and the contention that there is any "issue".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

197% = 2 threads exercising the cpu doing `sqrt()` in a loop, plus one thread which is not using any cpu because it is waiting for the other threads to finish in `pthread_join()`.